# How to load structure of page dynamically in angular

Tags: html, angular, angular-dynamic-components

i want to load structure of page  dynamically in container  component that means all div elements and CSS classes are loaded dynamically in angular ? how we can achieve this?

currently i am able to load component dynamically in this element but now i want go one step further ie. this html elements and structural div tags are loaded dynamically so that i am able  to defined page of structure different for different scenario

Comment: Are you saying, you want all HTML to be rendered by code?

Comment: yes. the container of components ie div elements with it classes col-sm-12 and others  that actually defines our page structure

Comment: This search will lead you. Be careful, you may want to 'santize' the injected HTML to prevent hackers.     https://www.google.com/search?q=angular+how+to+load+html+site:stackoverflow.com